# Which is the better way to instantiate a decimal?

Tags: c#, decimal, instantiation

```
private decimal? _income;

public SomeClassName()
{        
    // First way
    _income = new decimal(45000.75)

    // Second way  
    _income = Convert.ToDecimal(45000.75)
}
```

Which of the above two instantiation is better? Why?

Comment: Why you can't simply assign the value? `_income=45000.75m`

Comment: Because the compiler says the value 45000.75 is a double and cannot be assigned to nullable decimal

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin - because you'll get an error. `_income=45000.75m` on the other hand should be fine

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah, that's what I mean in fact :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) literal:

```
_income=45000.75m;
```

If, on the other hand, you have a non-constant value that is currently a `double`, I'd probably just use:

```
_income = (decimal)doubleValue;
```

Unless or until I've got a demonstrable reason that it's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about "m" suffix to use in decimal